# Shopify - Display Only the First Four Words in the Product Title in Ruby

Tags: ruby, shopify

[Show only : "Clip with Shining Red"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zA0Jl.png)

If the product is out of stock, add to cart button will be replaced by the first 4 words of the product's title. I have the code for this but it shows the whole product's title
[Here's the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0OaI.png)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What is the ruby code to show only the first 4 words of a Product Title?  This code shows the whole Product Title: <h1 class="product-single__title">{{ product.title }}</h1>

Answer (score 0):

When `product.title` returns the full title then

```
product.title.split.take(4).join(' ')
```

would return the first four words of that title.

Comment: Thank you so much. What do I need to put inside ('  ') ?

Comment: `split` splits the string at whitespaces and removes the whitespace by doing so. Therefore you need to add the whitespace again when joining the words. Just leave the `join(' ')` like it is...

Comment: Thanks for your time. You have answered it well.